# Installing from Github onto Kubuntu

Tags: software-installation, github

here's the question: Usually when I download programs, it's done via the Terminal using `sudo apt-get` or in the software center. But I want to install a [screenshot saver](https://github.com/ChrisZeta/Scrot-and-imgur-zenity-GUI) distributed through a remote git repository

In the Readme file, I saw no instructions on how to install it. I downloaded the zip file but now I don't know what to do.

---

PS What I want to achieve is:
each time I press PrtSc or ctrl+prsc I save a file named
`screenshot_todaysdate`
to 
`/Dropbox/folder`
and then the URL is pasted to my clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you extract the files in the zip, you will find a directory named:
`Scrot-and-imgur-zenity-GUI-master/src`
In this directory (scr) there are 2 `.sh` files.
If you execute the `zscreen.sh` script you will get questions what kind of screenshot you will make, and if you want to upload it.

if you look into this `zscreen.sh` file, you will see it will store its screenshots in `$HOME/Screenshots`. Here you can also change the filename to something you like more.

I am not sure how to upload the screenshots to dropbox (I don't have dropbox so I'm not sure), and it gives an error that it can't find `zimgur.sh`.

You have to edit the `zimgur.sh` file and make a list/replace zimgur for uploading :)